# Detecting permission changes in the setting page

Tags: android, permissions

I found out that when user change permission settings for Google apps in phone setting page, it show an alert to warn user that if they do so, the app might not function well.

[image: Permission deny]

Is there any way to add this alert on my app as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener) to get notified when a setting changes. You'll get the preference key and its value inside the listener. Based on this you can write an if statement and show a dialog.